# IBM RFT 9.1 : Object found but not clicked

Tags: java, rft

I am using RFT to test a couple of web applications in Internet Explorer. Note that I am not using it 'Out of the box', I am reading steps from an excel file and then calling the corresponding RFT method.

For example, in excel, if I have:

Click .id someElementId

Then RFT will find the element with .id=someElementId and click on it. It works very well for most of the application I am testing this way.

I am having problems with one particular application. The script for this application contains a lot of radio buttons being clicked and randomly, some radio button don't get clicked. Sometimes I am lucky and I'll get a working execution, but most of the time, RFT will miss at least one of the radio button.
**What's weird is that the radio button IS found, flashing red (highlight activated) and the mouse will go exactly in the middle of it, but won't click. Will then go to the next radio button, click with success and continue.**

Also, some coworker experienced some similar issue but with button/checkbox. Me I only got this with radio buttons

I tried lots and lots of things...The only way I was able to make it work, was to call invoke 3 times in the case of radio button. This is a temporary workaround, I want to find the root cause of my problem because even with this workaround, once in a while we experience the same issue.

Automatic enablement is unchecked. It made the execution faster but didn't solve my problem

I wait until browser ready state is 4 (And since the object is found, I suppose the browser is really in a ready state)

I tried giving RFT more RAM (I was desperate)

Any hint on why would RFT RANDOMLY miss a click, even if the element is found and the mouse placed right in the middle?